# How to merge projects from two branches into one

Tags: git, visual-studio

#### Scenario

Assume I have a Visual Studio solution that contains a single project named `ProjectA`. This solution lives on `branchA` in git. Then, there was a time when I branched off of `branchA` into `branchB` to create a different UI for the same product. The development of both, `branchA` and `branchB` continued independently. They still retain the same `ProjectA` name in both branches; the structure overall remained the same.

```
---branchA---x---x------x---------x
              \
               \---branchB---x---x
```

Current structure (on both branches)

```
- ProjectA
  ...
- Solution.sln
```

Future structure

```
- ProjectA
  ...
- ProjectB
  ...
- Solution.sln
```

#### Question

How do I merge `branchB` into `branchA` without overriding `branchA` code? In essence, I want to include `branchB`'s contents in `branchA` without sharing any code. **Ideally, I would like to retain the history** for `branchB` until the common ancestor.

#### Options

- Rename `branchB`'s `ProjectA` to `ProjectB` and fix the folder structure and lose history for `branchB`.
- Rewrite history as if the files were copied at the common ancestor's point before any of the modifications and additions happened.

#### What I tried

I tried various merge strategies (`no-rename`), but all of them move most of the contents.

Comment: How about `git merge branchB --strategy=ours`?

Comment: I'd choose option 1. `branchB` is not really lost then, it may fail to found automatically, but it is there still.

Comment: I think to merge you should `git merge -Xno-renames --no-commit`, and then revert all changes (removals) for `ProjectA` before committing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) the contents of ProjectA, merge B, and apply the stashed changes.

Comment: Does not seem to work. It carries the stash and will apply delete to all common files.